# Descargar archivo de un Branch de GITHUB

Tags: git, github

Hace un tiempo estoy involucrado en un proyecto de mi facultad, y un compañero subio archivos a un branch creado por él en un repositorio de guthub. Queria consultarles como hago para poder descargar esos archivos para poder modificarlos en mi pc.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Tienes Git instalado tú también? ¿Has clonado su repositorio?

Comment: sisi ya tengo clonado el repositorio, pero no me aparecen los archivos del branch

Comment: ¿has probado `git fetch origin su-rama`? Y después `git checkout su-rama`

Comment: no lo he probado, ahora lo intento, Gracias